# CUDA profiling aten::mul Does it only include calculation time or does it include time to access memory?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nsight

The following results were obtained by pytorch cuda

```
profiling.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name              Self CPU%      ...          Self CUDA              Self CUDA% ...
aten::mul          0.84%         ...           136.329ms               20.82%   ...
aten::nonzero     ...
.
.
```

I want to check if it takes more time to calculate or access memory when the function is executed.
I'm wondering if the time in aten::mul should I think that only computation time is calculated or that memory access time is included.
Thanks!

When I measured the time with the Nsight system, it takes a lot of time to access the memory, so I think the time calculated as atem::mul includes the memory access time, but I'm not sure, so I ask you guys

Comment: Im sorry, the format is wrong